# Кириллица в базе и вывод данных в цикле из базы MySQL

Tags: php, база-данных, циклы, mysql

Я новичок в программировании на php. У меня возникло 2 вопроса.

1. У меня почему-то данные из БД кириллицей выводит так: `?????????` Кодировку менял (cp1251, utf-8), на странице тоже. Все никак. В чем может быть дело?
2. Вопрос по циклам. Нужно из этой базы вывести все, что там есть. Я набрал такой код:

-

```
    $id = 0;
    while ($id = 5) {
        $query = "SELECT id,nick,name,sname,oname,email,icq,skype,site,note FROM clients
        WHERE id='++$id'";
        $a = queryMysql($query);
        $b = mysql_fetch_assoc($a);
        echo '<td>'.$b['id'].'</td>'.'<td>'.$b['name'].'</td>'.'<td>'.$b['sname'].'</td>'.'<td>'.$b['oname'].'</td>'.'<td>'.$b['nick'].'</td>'.'<td>'.$b['email'].'</td>'.'<td>'.$b['icq'].'</td>'.'<td>'.$b['skype'].'</td>'.'<td>'.$b['site'].'</td>'.'<td>'.$b['note'].'</td>';
    }
```

Понятно, что ничего не вышло. Что писать в скобках while не знаю, поэтому так написал, но даже 5 строк не выводится. По идее начинаем цикл с id = 1 и дальше, пока строки в БД не закончатся.

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Самым первым выполните запрос mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8"); если данные в UTF-8 хранятся

2)

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM clients");

while ($b= mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
echo '<td>'.$b['id'].'</td>'.'<td>'.$b['name'].'</td>'.'<td>'.$b['sname'].'</td>'.'<td>'.$b['oname'].'</td>'.'<td>'.$b['nick'].'</td>'.'<td>'.$b['email'].'</td>'.'<td>'.$b['icq'].'</td>'.'<td>'.$b['skype'].'</td>'.'<td>'.$b['site'].'</td>'.'<td>'.$b['note'].'</td>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

В таких случаях надо проверить несколько вещей:

- кодировка данных в БД
- кодировка подключения к БД
- кодировка, в которой сервер отдает данные
- кодировка, в которой браузер показывает страницу
- иногда кодировка самих файлов с программным кодом

если Вы видите ???????, это значит что где-то данные были неудачно преобразованы в utf-8